# How to split a String on the basis of a recurring substring?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string that I want to split into multiple components as follows:

> Timings: 12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI), 3PM - 6 PM (WED), 4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)

I want to split this string into its components i.e.

> Part - 1:  12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI)
>
> Part - 2:  3PM - 6 PM (WED)
>
> Part - 3:  4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)

I tried using Java's `string.split()` method but it only works with delimiters I guess hence if I split on a comma, I get 4 parts and so on. Is there anyway to split a string using a substring, in this case `),`.
Thanks a lot.
Here's a snippet of the code:

```
String temp = "12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI), 3PM - 6 PM (WED), 4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)";
String[] partsOfInput = temp.split("),");
String part1 = partsOfInput[0];
String part2 = partsOfInput[1];
String part3 = partsOfInput[2];
if(part3!=null)
    System.out.println(part1+part2+part3);
else
    System.out.println(part1+part2);
```

Comment: you can split on ending bracket and then append closing bracket to each element

Comment: you don't need ), just split base on , try this - 

String[] partsOfInput = temp.split(",");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Below Code

```
 String temp = "12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI), 3PM - 6 PM (WED), 4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)";
    String[] partsOfInput = temp.split("\\),");
    String part1 = partsOfInput[0]+")";
    String part2 = partsOfInput[1]+")";
    String part3 = partsOfInput[2];
    if(part3!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("part1-->"+part1);
       System.out.println("Part2->"+part2);
       System.out.println("part3-->"+part3);
    }
       else
        System.out.println(part1+part2);
}
```

OutPut:

```
part1-->12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI)
Part2--> 3PM - 6 PM (WED)
part3--> 4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String[] partsOfInput = temp.split("\\),");
```

but in this you need to append `)` at the end, no need to append `)` for last `String` if it doesn't end with `,`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just split using `temp.split(", ");` since there is no space in this part of string: `"(TUE,THU)"`.

So you can just do it like this in your case:

```
String temp = "12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI), 3PM - 6 PM (WED), 4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)";
String[] partsOfInput = temp.split(", ");
String part1 = partsOfInput[0];
String part2 = partsOfInput[1];
String part3 = partsOfInput[2];
if (part3 != null) {
    System.out.println(part1 + part2 + part3);
} else {
    System.out.println(part1 + part2);
}
```

And the value of the variables is:

```
String part1 = partsOfInput[0]; // -> 12:00 PM - 4:00 PM (MON-FRI)
String part2 = partsOfInput[1]; // -> 3PM - 6 PM (WED)
String part3 = partsOfInput[2]; // -> 4 PM- 8PM (TUE,THU)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiki, the code works for this case, but there are cases where there's space with the commas too. I figured it out, thanks a  lot though. Appreciate it.